# Auto create VPN account on CENTOS VPS server, with successful purchase of VPN subscription

Tags: php, linux, shell, centos, vpn

I was wondering if anyone knows if this would be the correct approach for going about this process.

I am making a VPN service as a project to further my computer programming background and portfolio.

I was wondering, after a successful verification purchase for a VPN subscription on www.example.com, would the correct route to auto create the subscribers VPN account be to:

Fire off a .sh (shell script) hosted on the server with PHP variables passed to the script for the $username & $password. Which in return will run on the server and create the subscribers access account.

Comment: correct=works, so does it?

Comment: You sound like the professors that inspired me to take my first programming classes at University of Mississippi. But I get your point, and I guess I was just being lazy wanting to know the best route before testing different ideas. I was just reading about WHMCS is this a good route?

Comment: sure if that's the type of account you want users to have, its a fine route